# how we can show progress bar while running big query and writing to xls file in php

Tags: php

how to show progress bar while running large mysql query. For example running some mysql query using php script taking more time to complete in mean time how to show the progress bar in that browser

Comment: I know its Friday 13th, but have you tried to google what you want? - #FLAGED - #LAZY -

Answer (score 0):

better use jquery ajax and php  for progress bar

see demo here http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax-progress2.php

Comment: ok. fine but ajax maximum execution timeout how much, my query is running minimum 40 min and max 1-2hr

Comment: @BalamuruganP why you dont use Database?

Comment: you can give timeout : 10000000 property also in ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can(t show a progress bar in php. You have to use jquery, and ajax.

Edit: YOU CAN'T, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: ok. fine but ajax maximum execution timeout how much, my query is running minimum 40 min and max 1-2hr . because it is running aroung 3L rows

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like PayPal does it while logging in. Display a page that just shows a progress bar. That page has a meta tag in  which redirects to the big query page. The progress bar will stay displayed until the server finished generating the response page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://domain.com/heavy-query.php">
```